# Why is GPIO level not being properly detected in VS Code? (Works in Arduino IDE)

Tags: c++, c, esp32, gpio, freertos

I'm building a project that has a ESP-32 / C++ powered door-sensor at the heart of its functionality. I'm taking it step by step and as of right now just want to confirm that my C++ is registering when the door sensor's GPIO output is high & when it is low. Regardless of whether the sensor is touching or not, the program is only registering that the GPIO output is LOW (0). If I go into Arduino IDE and write a similar programming using their libraries, it works as intended.

I have done the following:

- Tested all hardware: ESP32, breadboard, jumper wires, and door sensors all working fine.
- Tested code in Arduino IDE using their libraries for ESP32 / Arduino development, code worked as intended
- Confirmed that pins were configured correctly and that there were no problems with development environment or setup by writing a blink program with C++ in VSCode (worked as intended)

The above trials lead me to believe that it is an issue with the code itself but I'm stumped on what code possibly be causing it to not register the GPIO level change.

```
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

#define DOOR_PIN GPIO_NUM_19                                //GPIO 19 -> DOOR_PIN                          //GPIO 13 -> LED_PIN
#define LOG_LEVEL_LOCAL ESP_LOG_VERBOSE        
#define LOG_TAG "MAIN"

extern "C" void app_main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(DOOR_PIN);                 //Set up DOOR_PIN for IO              
    gpio_set_direction(DOOR_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);         //Set up DOOR_PIN as output pin     
    while(true)    
    {
        int DOOR_PIN_LEVEL = gpio_get_level(DOOR_PIN);
        if(DOOR_PIN_LEVEL == 1){                            
            ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, "High");                      //(Door sensors touching)
        }
        else{                 
            ESP_LOGI(LOG_TAG, "Low");                       //(Door sensors not touching)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`gpio_set_direction`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html#_CPPv418gpio_set_direction10gpio_num_t11gpio_mode_t) has an error code you are not checking. I'd start there.

Comment: What error code are you getting? Hasn't given me any errors.

Comment: Have you looked? `gpio_set_direction(DOOR_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);` discards the result code so you have no way of knowing if the direction was successfully set. At this point I'm just making sure there are no low-hanging fruit.

Comment: `gpio_set_direction(DOOR_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);` Why do you set the pin to OUTPUT? I am working with some ARM Cortex M0+ MCU where I need to use a different way to read back the pin status if they are set to output.

Comment: "Confirmed that pins were configured correctly" How did you do that? A blink program sounds like using a pin as output. Did you wire it to another pin you used as input?